# MVC 4 data validation message increases width of my form

Tags: css, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating quite simple form for my model. I have generated scaffolded "Edit" view for it with validation. One validation is for "URL" type and it is causing me problems.

I have this in view:

```
<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Server)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Server)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Server)
</div>
```

This is css for #content section that contains everything rendered by View:

```
#content
{
    border:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto ;
    margin-right: auto ;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    min-width:480px;
    max-width:800px;
    display:table;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

When page is loaded, #content is 480px wide and elements inside take up as much space as possible (editor-field elements and element with submit buttons are set to 100%, nothing else has width set in css).

When "required" validation message is displayed on fields, everything works ok (width doesnt change).

When I enter invalid URL, message is longer (localized version of default mesage says "Pole Server neobsahuje plně kvalifikovanou adresu URL protokolu http, https nebo ftp.") and the whole #content width changes to 657px;

Is there a way how I can keep the width as it was before validation message got displayed and wrap validation message in case it is too long into more than one line with css settings?

I would like to avoid fixed width settings (on main section and all elements including validation message divs) and still keep the layout template and its css universal so I can keep using it repeatedly without need for tailoring it to particular scenario where it is used.

Thanks in advance

I have included screenshot that shows how it looks like

[image: see screenshot how it looks like]

Comment: Use `max-width:480px;` so it will not exceed `480px`

Comment: or you could try using max-width:800px; min-width:auto; :)

Comment: My goal is to allow #content to be between 480px (less would look weird) and 800px (to comply with smaller screens). Since the template should be reusable, I do not want to limit the elements in #content because I do not know how much space those will need in general (i just know that in this particular case 480px is more than enough).

Comment: @Erchi So give a class for `#content` int his particular page and set `max-width:480px;`

Comment: you mean adding one more css file which will contain custom settings for this particular page?

Comment: That's one of the many reasons I rather display error messages on dialogs/tool tips.